# Keyname after the function name

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I'm using boto3 to verify if a cloudformation stack already exists. The code for this is:

```
import boto3
import botocore

conn = boto3.client('cloudformation')
list_stack = conn.list_stacks()['StackSummaries']
for stack in list_stack:
    if stack['StackStatus'] == 'DELETE_COMPLETE':
        continue
    if stack['StackName'] == stack_name:
        return True
return False
```

The `conn.list_stack()` returns a dict.

This code works properly.

What I don't understand is why I need to put ['StackSummaries'] after the list_stack()? I've never seen this kind of code where you put the key of a dictionary after the function. I just don get it the syntax.

And if I don use this way a get this error message:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

So I need to use with the suntax that I don understand. Can someone explain how this works?

Comment: This is equivalent to `stacks = conn.list_stacks(); list_stack = stacks['StackSummaries']`. Clearer?

Comment: Alternatively: `stacks = conn.list_stacks(); for stack in stacks['StackSummaries']: ...`.

Comment: Alternatively, just `print(conn.list_stacks())` to see what you're working with…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output for [`list_stacks()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.list_stacks) is:

```
{
    'StackSummaries': [
        {
            'StackId': 'string',
            'StackName': 'string',
            'TemplateDescription': 'string',
            'CreationTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'LastUpdatedTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'DeletionTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'StackStatus': 'CREATE_IN_PROGRESS'|'CREATE_FAILED'|'CREATE_COMPLETE'|'ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'|'ROLLBACK_FAILED'|'ROLLBACK_COMPLETE'|'DELETE_IN_PROGRESS'|'DELETE_FAILED'|'DELETE_COMPLETE'|'UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_COMPLETE'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE'|'REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS'|'IMPORT_IN_PROGRESS'|'IMPORT_COMPLETE'|'IMPORT_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'|'IMPORT_ROLLBACK_FAILED'|'IMPORT_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE',
            'StackStatusReason': 'string',
            'ParentId': 'string',
            'RootId': 'string',
            'DriftInformation': {
                'StackDriftStatus': 'DRIFTED'|'IN_SYNC'|'UNKNOWN'|'NOT_CHECKED',
                'LastCheckTimestamp': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
            }
        },
    ],
    'NextToken': 'string'
}
```

The outer-most dictionary element is `StackSummaries`, which contains a list.

So, it is returning the list.

Instead of:

```py
list_stack = conn.list_stacks()['StackSummaries']
for stack in list_stack:
```

they could have used:

```py
stacks = conn.list_stacks()
for stack in stacks['StackSummaries']:
```

The good thing is that they called it `list_stacks`, which suggests that the contents is a `list`.